# Using UICollectionView in an SKScene to implement horizontal scrolling menu

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uicollectionview

I am implementing a horizontal carousel-style character selection screen for a game (as per image below).

[Image of carousel effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVley.png)

The app is structured as one main `GameViewController` presenting different scenes; the `CharacterSelectionScene` being one of them.

From my research it seems that, although not always advisable to mix `UIKit` and `SpriteKit` elements, the best way to achieve the effect is the use a `UIColectionView` and add it as a subview to the scene. Because it takes care of the some of the animation and bounce effects.

[Horizontal scrolling in SpriteKit (vs. a viewcontroller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539841/horizontal-scrolling-in-spritekit-vs-a-viewcontroller)

However, it's giving me a real headache! Using the post above as an example, I subclassed `UICollectionView` but I am unable to use the `CharacterSelectionScene` as the datasource and delegate! This would be ideal as the scene is where the data is loaded in from a plist.

I am currently using my `CharacterCollectionView` as the datasource and delegate by passing data from the scene via the collection view's `init()` a la:

```
collectionView = CharacterCollectionView(frame: customFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout, characterData: characterData)
```

This works but feels like a bad idea, it feels like a bit of a bodge. Maybe I'm wrong but as a fairly new programmer I'd just like to do this the right way!

**Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I going down completely the wrong path here or is this a perfectly good way to move forward. All advise/pointers appreciated!**

Comment: check out this it might be what you are looking for. https://github.com/bwide/CollectionNode

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Much less confusing to implement. However it still doesn't quite match up to the UICollectionView in terms of smoothness. I'll try some tweaking around to see if I can get it any closer to what I'm after.